# How can I remove all old related items in an array list when I insert a new item? i.e. Cube 1 removed when adding Cube 2

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, arraylist

```
String[] total = new String[] {
  };

final List<String> total_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(total));
```

I add the `total` string 1 by 1 by pressing a button

```
total_list.add(newstring);
```

So, my array will be like this:

```
ArrayList {"Cube 1", "Cube 2", "Cube 3", "Square 1", "Square 2", "Square 3" ...}
```

How to delete the prior inserted data?

So when I add data array `Cube 3` all data with `Cube 1`, `Cube 2` will be deleted, and the other same too, `Square 1`, `Square 2` will be deleted when I insert `Square 3`.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Do you want to remove from `total_list` items with same name, but different index while adding new element?

Comment: why do you even need an arraylist if you will delete it anyway?

Comment: You should show clear about it.

Comment: @NorthernPoet yea, I try to add element by index n remove the others one with same name, I use total_list.set(1, "Cube 3"), error show up bcs index 1 do not exist, so I try this, maybe I can add arylist element what number I want, and replace or remove the arylist data/elemnt what I want too

Comment: @johnII I just try for fix my another problem :( if cant, okay ill find another way

Answer (score 0):

For the question that you ask, how to delete last new inserted data?

```
total_list.remove(total_list.size()-1);
```

This will remove the last new inserted data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this..removeAll will remove all the data and then you can add new data.

```
total_list.removeAll(total_list);

total_list.add("new item");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming all your items are like `<name><white-space><index>` and case-sensitive and assuming you list doesn't contain anything else, use this method to insert new items into it:

```
void addReplace(ArrayList<String> a, String s) {
    String name = s.split("\\s")[0];
    for (int i = a.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String item = a.get(i);
        if (item.startsWith(name))
            a.remove(i);
    }
}
```

But I recommend you to change data storage strategy, depending of what you need in real. Looks like you need to store some index for string keys. Try to looking at `sets` and `maps`.